# JQuery: Trying to append numbers into a text area on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble getting one of my buttons to append data to a HTML text area. The button in question is "BPI". I am trying to append a few digits of pi to my first text area. The other 4 buttons operate within the 2nd text area. Thank you in advance for your help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#BAddition').click(function(e) {
    $('#TOperator').val() += "+";

  })

  $('#BSubtract').click(function(e) {
    $('#TOperator').val() += "-";
  })

  $('#BMultiplication').click(function(e) {
    $('#TOperator').val() += "*";
  })

  $('#BDivision').click(function(e) {
    $('#TOperator').val() += "/";
  })

  $('#BPI').click(function(e) {
    $('#TFirstnum').val() += "3.141592657";
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Input:<br>
<textarea id="TFirstnum"></textarea>
<textarea id="TOperator"></textarea>
<textarea id="TSecondnum"></textarea>
<label id="LEquals"></label>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="" id="BAddition">+</button>
<button type="button" onclick="" id="BSubtract">-</button>
<button type="button" onclick="" id="BDivision">/</button>
<button type="button" onclick="" id="BMultiplication">*</button>
<button type="button" onclick="" id="BPI">&#960;</button>
<button type="button" onclick="" id="BEquals">=</button>
```

Comment: try `$('#TOperator').val($('#TOperator').val()  + "+")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a value use `$(yourObject).val("yourvalue")`

If you want to add a value to the already existing value use `$(yourObject).val($(yourObject).val() + "yourvalue")`

**Working example below**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#BAddition').click(function(e) {
    $('#TOperator').val($('#TOperator').val() + "+");

  })

  $('#BSubtract').click(function(e) {
    $('#TOperator').val($('#TOperator').val() + "-");
  })

  $('#BMultiplication').click(function(e) {
    $('#TOperator').val($('#TOperator').val() + "*");
  })

  $('#BDivision').click(function(e) {
    $('#TOperator').val($('#TOperator').val() + "/");
  })

  $('#BPI').click(function(e) {

    $('#TOperator').val($('#TOperator').val() + "3.141592657");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Input:<br>
<textarea id="TFirstnum"></textarea>
<textarea id="TOperator"></textarea>
<textarea id="TSecondnum"></textarea>
<label id="LEquals"></label>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="" id="BAddition">+</button>
<button type="button" onclick="" id="BSubtract">-</button>
<button type="button" onclick="" id="BDivision">/</button>
<button type="button" onclick="" id="BMultiplication">*</button>
<button type="button" onclick="" id="BPI">&#960;</button>
<button type="button" onclick="" id="BEquals">=</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to **set** an element's `value` attribute using Jquery, you need to set the value **inside** the parantheses: `.val('newValue')`.

When you want to **get** an element's value, use blank parantheses: `var x = elem.val()`.

So to concatenate (or append) values, you should use:

```
$('#TOperator').val($('#TOperator').val() + '+');
```

A **longer** version to elaborate:

```
var expr = $('#TOperator').val();  // Get current value
expr += '+';                       // Concatenate the + sign
$('#TOperator').val(expr);         // Set the new value
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is the expected result when you click this button? please try to explain.

Answer (score 0):

You are useing `+=` which does not work. You have to get the value, and then set the value;

```
$('#BAddition').click(function(e) {
    $('#TOperator').val( $('#TOperator').val() + "+");
});
```

---

You're repeating yourself a lot. I suggest you change the html a bit and create a much neater function.

```
<button type="button" class="MathSign" data-sign="+">+</button>
<button type="button" class="MathSign" data-sign="-">-</button>
<button type="button" class="MathSign" data-sign="/">/</button>
<button type="button" class="MathSign" data-sign="*">*</button>

<button type="button" id="BPI">&#960;</button>
<button type="button" class="MathSign" data-sign="=">=</button>


// handle the [+ - * / =] in one go:
$('.MathSign').on('click', function(){
    $('#TOperator').val( $('#TOperator').val() + $(this).data('sign'));

    // Or,you can drop the data-sign attribute and use the content of the button
    $('#TOperator').val( $('#TOperator').val() + this.innerHTML);
})
```

Comment: don't you have 1 `"` too much in `data-sign="=""`

Comment: Thanks, fixed it :)

Comment: Not a problem :)

Comment: I didn't think of using HTML class attributes to be able to process the inputs of several buttons at once. Thanks you for helping me improve my program more :)

Comment: Thats what we're for :) Just upvote the answers you like and maark the answer you think helped you most as answer

Answer (score 0):

`$(selector).val()` is used to get the value of the `input` box.

If you want to set the value, you need to pass the value `$(selector).val(value)`.

I have modified your example. One thing you need to consider is when you do `$(selector).val()`, you will get string. If you want to have addition instead of `concatenation` of two strings, You should probably use `parseInt`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#BAddition').click(function(e) {
    $('#TOperator').val($('#TOperator').val() + "+");
  })

  $('#BSubtract').click(function(e) {
    $('#TOperator').val($('#TOperator').val() + "-");
  })

  $('#BMultiplication').click(function(e) {
    $('#TOperator').val($('#TOperator').val() + "*");
  })

  $('#BDivision').click(function(e) {
    $('#TOperator').val($('#TOperator').val() + "/");
  })

  $('#BPI').click(function(e) {
    $('#TFirstnum').val($('#TFirstnum').val() + "3.141592657");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Input:<br>
<textarea id="TFirstnum"></textarea>
<textarea id="TOperator"></textarea>
<textarea id="TSecondnum"></textarea>
<label id="LEquals"></label>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="" id="BAddition">+</button>
<button type="button" onclick="" id="BSubtract">-</button>
<button type="button" onclick="" id="BDivision">/</button>
<button type="button" onclick="" id="BMultiplication">*</button>
<button type="button" onclick="" id="BPI">&#960;</button>
<button type="button" onclick="" id="BEquals">=</button>
```

Comment: I edited only the `BPI` button. Although I have edited other buttons also now.